# PostgrSQL Create extension timescale

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

hi i just can't install the timescaledb Extension in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE EXTENSION timescaledb
    VERSION "1.6.0";
```

after saving; the message `"Connection to Server has been lost"`

Google did not help; already trying for Hours... Help!!!!

```
== Saving changes to: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data\postgresql.conf
2020/03/18 21:39:26 Installing TimescaleDB library files...
2020/03/18 21:39:26 Success!
2020/03/18 21:39:26 Installing TimescaleDB control file...
2020/03/18 21:39:26 Success!
2020/03/18 21:39:26 Installing TimescaleDB SQL files...
2020/03/18 21:39:26 Success!
TimescaleDB installation completed successfully.
```

trying to create the Extension in the Shell gave me:

```
localdb=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
FATAL:  extension "timescaledb" must be preloaded
TIP:  Please preload the timescaledb library via shared_preload_libraries.

This can be done by editing the config file at: C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data/postgresql.conf
and adding 'timescaledb' to the list in the shared_preload_libraries config.
        # Modify postgresql.conf:
        shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'

Another way to do this, if not preloading other libraries, is with the command:
        echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'" >> C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data/postgresql.conf

(Will require a database restart.)
```

but `shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'` is addet to the list…

postgresql.conf-file:

```
# - Shared Library Preloading -

shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'    

#local_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'
#session_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'
#jit_provider = 'llvmjit'       # JIT library to use

# - Other Defaults -

#dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
```

What am i doing wrong here ????

Answer (score 1):

need a lot more information.  How/where have you installed TimescaleDB?   What happens when you omit the version string?  E.g.,

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;`

Are you seeing anything in logs?

Comment: no i don't see anythong in the logs. I installed it with the timescaledb/Setup.exe

Comment: Did you install Postgres via EnterpriseDB's installer?

Please see:

https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1398#issuecomment-528731198

Comment: @MikeFreedman Running `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;` on timescale cloud always results in a db error `db error: ERROR: extension "timescaledb" has already been loaded with another version` Do you know anything about why that is?